# SVG property vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" still scales stroke

Tags: html, svg, image-scaling

In `SVG`, I need the `PATH` stroke width to remain as is while `viewBox` property is changing. The SVG property `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` should accomplish that but it is not working as it suppose to.

Can someone explain why in the code below (check the [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKQrYL)) the stroke width still increases as viewbox changes? I would also appreciate a solution that makes strokes width constant regardless of viewbox.

**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKQrYL**

**HTML**

```
<div class="Item">
  <div class="Item-graphic">
    <svg id='scaling-stroke' width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2"/>
      <path d="M25 15 L 25 35" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/>
      <path d="M15 25 L 35 25" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <span>
    50 x 50 view box<br>
    200 x 200 dimensions<br>
    no vector effect
  </span>
</div>
<div class="Item">
  <div class="Item-graphic">
    <svg id='non-scaling-stroke' width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
      <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
      <path d="M25 15 L 25 35" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
      <path d="M15 25 L 35 25" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/>
    </div>
  </svg>
  <span>
    50 x 50 view box<br>
    200 x 200 dimensions<br>
    vector effect
  </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

svg {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Item {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: rgba(#fff, 0.6);
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.Item-graphic {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 220px;
}
```

**JS**

```
n=1;inc=1;
cvb = function(){
  vb = '' + n
  vb += ' ' + n
  vb += ' ' + 2*(25-n)
  vb += ' ' + 2*(25-n)
  $('#non-scaling-stroke').attr('viewBox', vb)
  $('#scaling-stroke').attr('viewBox', vb)
  n += inc;
  if (n<=1 || n>=24) inc *= -1;
  setTimeout(cvb, 100);
}; 
cvb()
```

Comment: Presumably a chrome bug. It doesn't happen on Firefox.

Comment: You are right. It is working on FireFox and Safari. Chrome seems to have a bug and Microsoft Edge seems to not even support non-scaling-stroke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug in Chrome. The bug report is here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849080. It was fixed in Chrome version 68.0.3440.25.